# Auto login bot doesnt press next button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

so I was making an "app" to solve lessons for you! On a website called "eduka" here's a link to it https://klase.eduka.lt/auth sometimes even the first input would fail but I never got passed the next button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
import tkinter as tk
import time

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 250, bg = '#afeeee')
canvas1.pack()

canvas1.create_text(150,15,fill="darkblue",font="Helvetica 15",
                        text="username")

canvas1.create_text(150,58,fill="darkblue",font="Helvetica 15",
                        text="password")

canvas1.create_text(150,100,fill="darkblue",font="Helvetica 15",
                        text="URL")

entry_1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(150, 40, window=entry_1)

entry_2 = tk.Entry (root)  
canvas1.create_window(150, 80, window=entry_2)

entry_3 = tk.Entry (root)  
canvas1.create_window(150, 120, window=entry_3)

def get_answers():
    u_r_l = entry_3.get()
    user_name = entry_1.get()
    pass_word = entry_2.get()
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get((u_r_l))
    username = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'studentEmail')))
    username.send_keys(user_name)
    Button1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn btn-round btn-azure')))
    Button1.click()
    password = browser.find_element_by_id('studentPassword')
    password.send_keys(pass_word)
    Button2 = browser.find_element_by_id('btn btn-round btn-half btn-azure btn--with-loader')
    Button2.click()


button1 = tk.Button(text='DONE', command=get_answers)
canvas1.create_window(150, 180, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Im new to python and stack overflow it's my first time here I made an account just for this.
plz help me I'm going crazy I can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: Have you tried sending the enter key?

Comment: Have you done any debugging?